# React Native - Haste Package was found . however the module could not be found error

Tags: android, react-native

Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: While resolving module `KUDA/app/src/images/KUDA2.png`, the Haste package `KUDA` was found. However the module `app/src/images/KUDA2.png` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

> - `KUDA2.png`   *
>     `C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\app\src\images\KUDA2.png\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
>     at resolveHasteName (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:190:9)
>     at Object.resolve (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:68:20)
>     at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:161:273)
>     at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
>     at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
>     at dependencies.map.relativePath (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
>     at Array.map ()
>     at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
>     at C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Kuda\KUDA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:212:33
>     at Generator.next ()  BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░ 43.2% (316/481), failed.

The piece of code that threw this error is

```
<Image source={require('KUDA/app/src/images/KUDA2.png')} style={styles.logoImage}/>
```

I deleted the entire folder. Created a new project with the same name. I commented out the part of the code which had KUDA2.png in it. Still it shows the same error. I found a few solution on git but none of them work for me. 
I don't' understand why it is treating a simple png file as a module. 
Can anyone help me?. Thanks in Advance!.

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Hey @bennygenel Thanks for the response.
What is it exactly that you want me to add over here. I have commented out every line of code that has KUDA2.png in it. So i don't know what exactly you are looking for. There are just 2 files that i have touched til now. App.js and index.js. I wanted to use KUDA2.png as the logo image for my welcome screen. As soon as i added the following line  -------
<Image source={require('KUDA/app/src/images/KUDA2.png')} style={styles.logoImage}/> ------
It threw this error